# СлОган или слогАн?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика

Как правильно ставить ударение: слОган или слогАн, грАфити или графИти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оба слова новые, сравнительно недавно пришедшие в русский язык.  Тем не менее - **слОган** однозначно. Второе слово зафиксировано с разным произношением, но все-таки в большинстве словарей -  гра**фф**Ити

Comment: а почему два ФФ?

Answer (score 0):

Все зависи от того, из какого языка взяты данные слова. "Слоган" - конечно, ударение на О, потому что это слово английское, где вообще ударения почти всегда падают на первый слог. Насчет "граффити" - не знаю, но по звучанию похоже на итальянское, где ударение падает чаще всего на предпоследний слог.

Comment: Я считала, что "слоган" слово русское.

Answer (score 0):

СлОган. Ссылка на английское происхождение термина не совсем корректна: у нас хватает английских заимствований, где ударение не на первом слоге: джакузи, трамвай, троллейбус, футбол.

ГраффИти - бесспорно